# In App purchase products not working in IPv6

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am using In App Purchase with my app. Everything works fine for IPv4 network. But for IPv6 network I am not able to get list of products from iTunes. Due to this my app is getting rejected. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Don't look for IPv6 error as it is not clear by apple and it may not be the issue. One of my app got rejected and apple said its because of IPv6 network but after wasting whole day I figured it out and it was just the if condition which made my app stuck at login page. So my advice look for other bugs too which may cause this problem.

Comment: Actually, for me, it is not loading products in in-app purchase. But as per apple report, they are able to load it and while trying to use its crashing. I am totally blank about how they were able to load products in IPv6 ?